# multiline copy into ipython terminal breaks on empty lines

Tags: ipython

Until recently, I would write code in vim, select multiple lines, including functions, with the mouse and then middle click in a terminal where I am running ipython to paste everything inside. I would then get it pasted as a block, that I can still edit, and just click enter past the last line to run it.

However, this has now broken. First of all, %autoindent has been switched on by itself. I never had that option on before, since it destroys the pastes by adding extra four spaces on every indented line. This I could turn off.

My second issue, that I have not found a solution for, is that whenever I copy a block and ipython either detects a nonindented line, or if ipython sees an empty line, it will execute everything above.

As an example:

```
def IwillBreak(hello):
    i=5+2
    j=i+1

    z=i+j
    return z
```

I will get the following happen in the terminal (with %autoindent on):

```
In [1]: def IwillBreak(hello):
   ...:         i=5+2
   ...:             j=i+1
  Cell In[1], line 3
    j=i+1
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent


In [2]: 

In [2]:     z=i+j
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 z=i+j

NameError: name 'i' is not defined

In [3]:     return z
  Cell In[3], line 1
    return z
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function


In [4]:
```

or with %autoindent off:

```
In [8]: def IwillBreak(hello):
   ...:     i=5+2
   ...:     j=i+1
   ...: 

In [9]:     z=i+j

In [10]:     return z
  Cell In[10], line 1
    return z
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function


In [11]:
```

whereas before I would simply get the full block pasted into the terminal in one single "cell", where I could then edit it if I wanted to or just run it. Only if the first line in the function is empty, or if the first lines are comments and then one empty line, will it keep everything as one block. E.g. the following can be copied as normally:

```
def IwillNotBreak(hello):

    i=5+2
    j=i+1
    z=i+j
    return z
```

and also this works:

```
def IwillNotBreak(hello):
    # comment
    #
    # comment

    i=5+2
    j=i+1
    z=i+j
    return z
```

Another example:

```
i=1
j=2
z=3
```

if I paste this into the terminal I get the following:

```
In [4]:    i=1

In [5]: j=2

In [6]: z=3
```

whereas in the past, all three lines would be in the same cell. Also notice the spaces before "i=1", these remain from my previous copy and should not be there either.

I find this sudden change very bizarre. I have not updated any software on my computer or logged out for 69 days. I have not sourced anything or started using other ipython bins. I did just now try to update my ipython version from 7.28.0 to 8.12.2. It did however not solve the issue.

I can copy to the normal clipboard using ctrl+c and then use %paste in ipython without any of the above issues, but this is very tedious and also does not allow me to edit the block before executing it.

To clarify, by empty lines I mean lines that are either completely empty, or only contain whitespace. Usually I will have a few spaces on the empty lines, corresponding to the actual indentation level.

Many thanks for your help